# Highcharter bar colors issue

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have the following function:

```
library(highcharter)
hchart(
  newdata,
  "bar",
  hcaes(
    x = Gender,
    group = is_churner,
    y = Percent,
    label = Nominal,
    color = color
  )
) %>%
  hc_title(text = "") %>%
  hc_yAxis(
    title = list(text = ""),
    labels = list(format = "{value}")
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(
    pointFormat = "
      Percent: {point.y:,.0f}%<br>
      Nominal: {point.label:,.0f}<br>"
  )
```

The function takes a dataframe such as the following:

```
newdata <- data.frame(
  Gender = c(rep("Female", 2), rep("Male", 2)),
  is_churner = c("Active", "Churner", "Active", "Churner"),
  Nominal = c(7267L, 933L, 9767L, 1313L),
  Percent = c(42.7, 41.5, 57.3, 58.5), 
  color = c("green", "red", "green", "red")
) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(is_churner)
```

One of the columns - color is supposed to be mapped to the color argument of the hchart function. As far as I recall, this is something that used to work.

Now, however, I get a really ugly graph.

Neither the colors of the bars correspond to the colors column, nor the legend below (which is what the colors represent) are colored accordingly.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the color has to be called separately outside `hcaes`, but your approach seems more intuitive/sensible, so shame it's not working. The following works:

```
hchart(
  newdata,
  "bar",
  hcaes(
    x = Gender,
    group = is_churner,
    y = Percent,
    label = Nominal
  ), color = c("green", "red")
) %>%
  hc_title(text = "") %>%
  hc_yAxis(
    title = list(text = ""),
    labels = list(format = "{value}")
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(
    pointFormat = "
    Percent: {point.y:,.0f}%<br>
    Nominal: {point.label:,.0f}<br>"
  )
```

The following also works:

```
hchart(
  newdata,
  "bar",
  hcaes(
    x = Gender,
    group = is_churner,
    y = Percent,
    label = Nominal
  )
) %>%
  hc_title(text = "") %>%
  hc_yAxis(
    title = list(text = ""),
    labels = list(format = "{value}")
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(
    pointFormat = "
    Percent: {point.y:,.0f}%<br>
    Nominal: {point.label:,.0f}<br>"
  ) %>% 
  hc_colors(c("green", "red"))
```

I've deleted color from `hcaes` and added it instead to `hc_colors`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, in my case it turned out that my css files overruled the colors I specified in the `hchart` color.

When I removed te relevant lines in the css files the color command did work in the way you originally specified. You do not need to call it separately outside `hcaes`.